# UIView with blurred border

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

Is there a way to blur/fade out the border of a UIView?

i have done very little to none with core graphics so far.

Comment: haven't done anything yet. I'm hoping the library has a way to do it already, similar to doing rounded corners. If i need to do custom work with core graphics, the effect isn't worth the time involved to learn it right now.

Comment: have you read the **[UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)** already?

Comment: There's no built in way to do this. You can fade by masking with a fading gradient CALayer which is not too hard. Blur is a very different problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might try setting the UIView's CALayer with a large shadow radius and transparency.  Something like:

```
    #include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

...

```
    CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
    layer.shadowOpacity = .5;
    layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
    layer.shadowRadius = 10;
```

Comment: Ha, this works perfectly! i had thought about using the shadow but i wasn't sure how to get the shadow to go all around the UIView. Thanks!

Comment: works for me partially only. Maybe it is because I applied a perpective transform - the  blurred border is for points nearest to user only

Comment: how to do it without using shadows? I mean what if I wanted the image itself to fade? and not using any color on its edges and I mean edges which are defined by a uibezierpath? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an example with the swift version:

```
    btnSignIn.layer.cornerRadius = btnSignIn.frame.height * 0.5
    btnSignIn.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    btnSignIn.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    btnSignIn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    btnSignIn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
```

Result:

[image]

Keep in mind that if you change the shadow settings in the ib editor, it will change the text's shadow, not the view's border.

Also you can make a class and set it in IB Builder:

```
class UIRoundedWhiteButton: UIButton {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height * 0.5
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
}...
```